# Manipulating windows of other applications with .NET?

Tags: .net, windows-7

is it somehow possible to manipulate a window of another running application with code in my own with .NET (Windows 7)?
I often use PuTTY and would find it very helpful if I could write a program which adds key shortcut which does the same as right clicking the taskbar in Windows 7 and choosing "Show windows side by side" but not for all windows. Just for every open instance of PuTTy, so I have an overview of every open shh connection.
I hope this doesn't sound to confusing.
Anyway, to achiev this, I need to be able to manipulate other windows (in this case the PuTTY windows), e.g., resizing, moving, showing/hiding, etc., them.

If at all possible, I'd like to stick with C#, not C/C++

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

This definitely should be possible, but will need a whole arsenal of platform invokes. The relevant WINAPI functions to invoke would be [EnumWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633497%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve all top-level windows, [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve the location, size and title of each window and finally [MoveWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633534%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to move and resize the appropriate windows.

Good luck!